# bash/readline equivalent of escape-dot in vi-mode

Tags: bash, vi, readline

Having recently switched to vi-mode in bash, the one thing I miss is <kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> to get the last argument of the last command.

I know about <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd>, but I always end up hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> instead.

Is there another vi-mode equivalent for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the closest solution to what you want is this:

In your .bashrc, right after "set -o vi"...

```
set -o vi
bind -m vi-command ".":insert-last-argument
```

This tells your bash to invoke the "insert-last-argument" action when '.' is used in vi-command mode. This of course means that you lose the normal "." functionality of VI; but if you are like me, you'll prefer this.

**Addendum**:
You may also want <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> to work (those were the ones I was missing the most):

```
bind -m vi-command ".":insert-last-argument
bind -m vi-insert "\C-l.":clear-screen
bind -m vi-insert "\C-a.":beginning-of-line
bind -m vi-insert "\C-e.":end-of-line
bind -m vi-insert "\C-w.":backward-kill-word
```

Comment: Sadly this solution won't cycle through the arguments.

Comment: I know this is super old.  But my coworker just showed me the following which replicates the behavior exactly except that it adds a space ( go figure ).  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to map it to an Esc-. combo successfully.  So there is some muscle memory to break.  Anyway, here you go:
bind -m vi-insert C-k:yank-last-arg

I chose C-k just because it wasn't used for anything useful and seemed analogous "Ctrl Up".

Comment: Are the dots at the end of every keystroke really necessary? Compare to [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29989074/2192488).

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the following to restore the emacs "escape-dot inserts last argument" behaviour in vi mode:

```
bindkey -v '\e.' insert-last-word
```

Answer (score 4):

## By altering or adding ~/.inputrc

To restore certain bash goodies in vi-mode, simply alter or add **~/.inputrc** like this:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set show-all-if-unmodified on

set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-insert

$if mode=vi
"\C-a": beginning-of-line
"\C-e": end-of-line
"\C-l": clear-screen
"\C-n": next-history
"\C-p": previous-history
"\C-w": backward-kill-word

"\e.": yank-last-arg
"\e_": yank-last-arg
$endif
```

Here are [more bindable readline bash commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands).

Answer (score 2):

I always used <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> to get the last argument of the last command.

Also, the `!$` will give you the last argument of the last command executed.  There are a bunch of cool things you can do with the exclamation point, just check out the man page for bash and search for History Expansion.

Comment: I don't think <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> works in vi mode.

History Expansion is cool though. I knew about a few things, but not where to find the rest.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using $_ bash variable?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you can still use the equivalent for vi mode, which should be "ESC + ."

Comment: in vi mode, esc+. takes you to insert mode and then . repeats the last thing you typed. so: touch test.txt; vi "esc+." would give you vivi as the second line.